# error while adding a service reference

Tags: .net, wcf

I am getting following error

> The document at the url    was not recognized as a known document type.
>   The error message from each known type
>   may help you fix the problem:
>   - Report from '     is 'The document format is not recognized (the
>   content type is 'text/html;charset=UTF-8').'.
>   - Report from 'DISCO Document' is 'There was an error downloading
>   .svc?disco'.'.
>   - The remote name could not be resolved:
>   - Report from 'WSDL Document' is 'The document format is not recognized
>   (the content type is 'text/html;charset=UTF-8').'.
>   - Report from 'XML Schema' is 'The document format is not recognized (the
>   content type is 'text/html;charset=UTF-8').'. Metadata contains a
>   reference that cannot be resolved: ' 
>   '. Content Type application/soap+xml;
>   charset=utf-8 was not supported by
>   service . The client and service
>   bindings may be mismatched. The remote
>   server returned an error: (415) Cannot
>   process the message because the
>   content type 'application/soap+xml;
>   charset=utf-8' was not the expected
>   type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'.. If
>   the service is defined in the current
>   solution, try building the solution
>   and adding the service reference
>   again.

Answer (score 1):

The key is in the line:

> The remote name could not be resolved:
>   'imriskserver-02'

It looks like your server is not known - can you ping the server using the name? How about the IP address?

If you find that you can contact the server by IP address but not by name, you have a name resolution failure.  You can work around this by [editing the hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29).  This will work as long as the server IP address doesn't change.

There is more information about host name resolution on [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727005.aspx).

Comment: i am able to ping the server using ip adress but not using the name

Comment: if i have to use the ipaddress how can i change and where do i need to make the changes

Comment: @Peddireddy: Probably easier to edit the hosts file - see link in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the Web Service after you added it to your VS project? I would update it or add it again.

Comment: I am trying to add the reference using IP Address only

Comment: The error indicates that the server cannot be contacted - therefore cannot update service reference.